# Give the image of the set under mapping

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

> Consider $D = \{(x, y) | 1 \le x \le 2, 2 \le y \le 3\}$ and the mapping $(u, v) = (xy, x^2 - y^2)$. Find the image of $D$ under this mapping.

From combining the inequalities, I got $2 \le xy \le 6 \implies 2 \le u \le 6$. Is this part right?

I get $1 \le x^2 \le 4$ and $4 \le y^2 \le 3$, but I am aware I cannot directly combine these.

What can I do next? Will $u, v$ be dependent on each other somehow?

Comment: Apply the mapping to each of the $4$ boundary segments of the input region, and graph the $4$ resulting curves. Each of the $4$ curves is a portion of a parabola, so the boundary of the output region consists of $4$ (distinct) parabolic segments

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ochpwc8dcj ... might help ? (a bit)

Comment: For example, the bottom segment of the input rectangle has $y=2$ (constant), with $x$ varying from $1$ to $2$. For that input segment, the output curve has the parametric form
$$u = 2x,\;\;v=x^2 - 4$$
where the parameter $x$ varies from $1$ to $2$. If you eliminate the parameter, you get $v$ as a quadratic function of $u$, where $u$ varies from $2$ to $4$. That's one piece of the boundary of the output region. Three more to go. Routine, but no shortcuts.

Comment: To justify why the boundary of the output region is just the image of the boundary of the input region, show that the map $(x,y) \to (u,v)$ is one-to-one on the input region (you can solve uniquely for $(x,y)$ in terms of $(u,v)$).

Comment: Moreover, the inverse is continuous, so the map is a homeomorphism. Hence, the output region is homeomorphic to the input region (which is a square). In particular, the output region has no holes.